# "GPU at BusId 0x4 doesn't have a supported video decoder"

Tags: nvidia, vdpau

I have an Nvidia GeForce 940M GPU in my laptop:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep NVIDIA
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] [10de:1347] (rev a2)
```

I use the proprietary nvidia driver version 387.12:

```
$ nvidia-smi | head
Sat Oct 28 10:39:43 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 387.12                 Driver Version: 387.12                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940M        Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    204MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

According to the [driver documentation](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/387.12/README/supportedchips.html), VDPAU features of my GPU should be supported.

Yet, when I actually try, it fails:

```
$ vdpauinfo
display: :0   screen: 0
GPU at BusId 0x4 doesn't have a supported video decoder
Error creating VDPAU device: 1
```

Naturally, media players can't use hardware acceleration either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears, GM108M chips don't have a working video decoding hardware. The video decoding capabilities on systems with those chips are expected to be supported by the embedded Intel GPU.

How to make this arrangement work properly on Linux is an open question at this particular time.

Comment: Its 2020 and Linux is not ready for user by lay people...

Comment: Any updates on this in 2022?

Comment: With NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] [10de:1d12] and nvidia-driver 515.48.07, it still not work. But based on the kernel doc and nvidia supported product list, it should work, any idea?